# Find occurrences of string and replace using C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a huge string in json format.

the problem is it is not well formatted.

What i want to do is to find occurrences of some tags and replace it's values with some other values

What i want to search for is  this string `"distanceP":\somtext,   and "distance":\sometext,`

i want these two string to be replace with   `"distanceP":"\somtext",   and "distance":"\sometext",`

The string could be LIKE `"distanceP":\u1633, OR  "distance":\u16asa3, OR  "distanceP":\u1633sass,`

Please not the quotation marks and back-slash signs are included.

Can anyone please tell me REGEXP expression to search and replace with my own values.

Comment: I can't believe this question hasn't been already asked.

Comment: sorry i don't know REGEX

Comment: @user2539602 Then you should learn it.

Comment: That is why i have posted question

Comment: what @tnw means is learn from some tutorial/material. Posting a question doesn't necessarily means learning rather requesting for help or answer. Moreover, why not go by the below answer when you exactly know the token to search? Why regexp?

Comment: @user2539602 Is that really your intention? You literally said "tell me the REGEXP", that sounds like a demand to have someone write it for you. The scope of the site doesn't include teaching concepts.

Comment: No i don't exactly know the token, i just know the format like i have mentioned above, `"distanceP":\u1633,` OR  `"distanceP":\u16asa3,` OR  `"distanceP":\u1633sass,`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `string.Replace("\"distanceP\":\\", "\"distance\":\\")`? The `\` in the string escapes the next character, in effect forcing it to be part of the string as a literal. So `\\` turns into `\` in the string. And `Replace` will do what you're looking for, replace a given string with another string. I don't think you need RegEx for this.

Comment: No it is not like that there are multiple occurrences of string `"distanceP":\sometext, and "distance":\sometext,`

Comment: so i want to search occurences of `"distanceP":\sometext,` and then replace this with `"distanceP":"\sometext",`

Comment: The idea still applies, regardless of what the tokens and replacements are. Just use `string.Replace(TOKEN, REPLACEMENT)`.

Comment: No i don't exactly know the token, i just know the format like i have mentioned above, `"distanceP":\u1633,` OR  `"distanceP":\u16asa3,` OR  `"distanceP":\u1633sass,`